# Incorporating feature error into the Random Forest algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am using Random Forest to classify a large number of astronomical objects and it's doing a relatively good job. However, I want to improve the performance further by incorporating information about each feature's variance (or errorbar).

In astronomy, every measurement typically has an associated error bar. For example, if I measure the red color and the blue color, each color measurement would be a measure of brightness (in astronomy, that is the magnitude of a star), an the error, e.g. R magnitude 14 +- 0.2, B magnitude 12 +- 0.15.

I want to work out how to make Random Forest use the error bar as an extra piece of information. Any ideas?

Comment: you can try to concatenate the variances as extra features

Comment: Yep. I have tried that. It helps a little bit but it's not the best solution. You are still not using the error of the feature simultaneously with the feature itself.

Comment: Would be a cool new classifier "variance aware random forests", which takes variances into account for numeric features.

Comment: but I suppose such "variance aware random forests" classifier does not currently exist?

Comment: I sadly don't know about them, but would be a cool thing to try out and implement though.

Comment: Ok. I am going to add a feature to the R randomforest package to do this. =)

Comment: Have you done it? I really think it is an interesting topic

Answer (score 0):

are both error and color measurement numerical features? Then I would simply add a new feature which is a product of both the features, I suppose this is what you call as interactions in R

Answer (score 0):

one simple thing you can consider doing is resampling your data using the error distribution on each variable. so, you generate new examples by taking x + u*sigma, where u is a normal(0,1) draw and sigma is the sd of the error for that variable. it could take a lot of additional samples to properly incorporate the noise (depending on number of features) but since RFs are pretty fast to train in parallel, it could be an easy way to proceed. also has the added advantage of making it easy to incorporate correlated noise in the sampling.